# Number of Divisors is Increasing

Tags: number-theory, divisor-counting-function

Let $d(x) =$ (number of positive divisors of x)

Then, this proposition is true? If it is true, how can I proof it?

"Is there always exist positive $k$ for all $n$ such that $d(k) < d(k+1) < d(k+2) < ... < d(k+n-1)$ "

Sorry for my poor English.
Thank you.

Comment: This would be strongly tied to frequency of primes. If this is true, then it would mean that there are always two primes with at least $n-1$ non-primes in between. I do not know how I feel about that and I do not know if this is easy to prove at all.

Comment: I believe this is a true proposition that can be proved with sieve techniques; however, the proof I have in mind would not be particularly easy (it would involve mathematics that a specialist would first see in graduate school probably).

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas: it is definitely true that there are arbitrarily long intervals of consecutive composite numbers (to find $n-1$ in a row, take for example $n!+2$, $n!+3$, ..., $n!+n$).

Comment: @GregMartin Great point!

Comment: [Prime Gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap) might help.

Comment: @GregMartin What approach do you have in mind ?

Comment: Sieve methods can produce a constant $k(n)$ such that every admissible $n$-tuple of linear polynomials infinitely often has simultaneous values with at most $k(n)$ prime factors. Let $q_0,\dots,q_{n-1}$ be pairwise coprime squarefree numbers where $q_j$ has $2jk(n)$ prime factors. By CRT, we can find an arithmetic progression of $m$ such that $q_j\mid(m+j)$ for each $0\le j\le n-1$. This can be converted into $n$ linear polynomials, and the sieve result will show each $d(m+j)$ is between $2^{2jk(n)}$ and $2^{3jk(n)}$.